# How to find and print location (row and column) of searched element in two dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am a complete programming newbie currently learning about arrays. I wanted to print out the number `7` in the console, which worked. Now, I also want to print out the specific line and row in which the number 7 is located: "7 is located in line 2 and row 1.". How can I find line and column for number `7`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        int[][] array2 = {
                {3,4,5},
                {1,3,6},
                {5,7,9}
        };
        System.out.println(array2[2][1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are asking about printing here you go: `System.out.println(array2[2][1]+" is located in line 2 and row 1.");`. Of is your *real* question about *finding/locating* position(s) of `7` in this array?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer and efforts. Yes, my question was regarding in locating it. The solution by the other user is what I searched for. Sorry for making it not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int elementSearched = 7;
    int[][] array2 = {
            {3, 4, 5},
            {1, 3, 6},
            {5, 7, 9}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < array2[0].length; j++) {
            if (array2[i][j] == elementSearched) {
                System.out.println(elementSearched + " is located in line " + i + " and row " + j + ".");
            }
        }
}
```

array2[0] is used to get the sizew of the row (3 in this case)

The main thing that is done here is just brute-force search trough the array with 2 for loops.